# Synchronous AJAX requests in mobile widgets

Tags: javascript, widget, mobile-phones, w3c

I'm having troubles with a synchronous AJAX call in a JIL widget. Only the asynchronous version seems to work. What call types do you usually use sync or async?

Comment: I'd say the general rule is that you never use sync :) Please add more detail about your situation, some code and what exactly doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runtime implementation does not support the synchronous version of XMLHttpRequest. So, always use async.